# Mysql 'Copying to tmp table' very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, ee-1.14

I noticed that when I access Admin > Reports > Shopping Cart > Products in cart report in Magento EE 1.14 it gets times out. In mysql it gets stuck in 'Copying to tmp table' State for like 30 minutes!

Below is the query:

```
Command: Query
Time: 1650
State: Copying to tmp table
Info: SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN `product_name`.`value` AS `name`, product_price.value * main_table.base_to_global_rate AS `price`, `e`.*, COUNT(quote_items.item_id) AS `carts`, `order_items`.`orders` FROM `sales_flat_quote` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `sales_flat_quote_item` AS `quote_items` ON quote_items.quote_id = main_table.entity_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = quote_items.product_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `product_name` ON product_name.entity_id = e.entity_id AND product_name.attribute_id = 71
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `product_price` ON product_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND product_price.attribute_id = 75
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS `orders`, `oi`.`product_id` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `oi` GROUP BY `oi`.`product_id`) AS `order_items` ON order_items.product_id = e.entity_id WHERE (main_table.is_active = 1) GROUP BY `quote_items`.`product_id` LIMIT 20
Rows_sent: 0
Rows_examined: 551620
Rows_read: 551620
```

Query EXPLAIN EXTENDED:

```
mysql> explain extended SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN `product_name`.`value` AS `name`, product_price.value * main_table.base_to_global_rate AS `price`, `e`.*, COUNT(quote_items.item_id) AS `carts`, `order_items`.`orders` FROM `sales_flat_quote` AS `main_table`
    ->  INNER JOIN `sales_flat_quote_item` AS `quote_items` ON quote_items.quote_id = main_table.entity_id
    ->  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = quote_items.product_id
    ->  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `product_name` ON product_name.entity_id = e.entity_id AND product_name.attribute_id = 71
    ->  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `product_price` ON product_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND product_price.attribute_id = 75
    ->  LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS `orders`, `oi`.`product_id` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `oi` GROUP BY `oi`.`product_id`) AS `order_items` ON order_items.product_id = e.entity_id WHERE (main_table.is_active = 1) GROUP BY `quote_items`.`product_id` LIMIT 20;
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                               | key                                            | key_len | ref                               | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | main_table    | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                     | NULL                                           | NULL    | NULL                              | 349938 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | quote_items   | ref    | IDX_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID,IDX_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID                                                                     | IDX_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID             | 4       | prod.main_table.entity_id   |      2 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | e             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                     | PRIMARY                                        | 4       | prod.quote_items.product_id |      1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | product_name  | ref    | UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID | UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID | 6       | prod.e.entity_id,const      |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | product_price | ref    | UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_ATTRIBUTE_ID  | UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID  | 6       | prod.e.entity_id,const      |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                        | NULL                                           | NULL    | NULL                              |   7512 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | oi            | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                        | NULL                                           | NULL    | NULL                              | 539047 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set, 1 warning (0.58 sec)
```

We have tried allowing temporary table creation in memory instead of disk, without any luck.

Anyone else experiencing similar problem? Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is this accurate? `product_price.value * main_table.base_to_global_rate AS 'price', `. Could you show an EXPLAIN?

Comment: @Melvyn updated

Comment: Try removing the WHERE and adding it to the first join condition. What does explain say then? So: `INNER JOIN `sales_flat_quote_item` AS `quote_items` ON quote_items.quote_id = main_table.entity_id AND main_table.is_active=1`

Comment: did not helped, it's showing same explain as original

Comment: Yah, I see. You can't connect sales_flat_order_item to catalog_catetgory_entity cause a deletion of a product would either have to be denied or result in deletion of order_item rows. I'd ditch the join then do a second query for the sales data and handle it in the output.

Comment: Hmm, but as it's a core query I will hesitate to modify it.

Comment: Yes, probably  you should use the EE you're paying for ;-)

Comment: They always want ton of information to help me even for small things, wasting my hours unnecessarily, that scares me to ask anything to them.

Comment: You may be in luck. We have client about to upgrade to EE 1.14 and this case worries me. If I can reproduce it, I'll put in the ticket and disable the report in live site until it's fixed. I have one hunch... Can you do a mysql -e "show full processlist" when this happens? Anonymize values if needed, as long as table relations remain in tact.

Comment: I can reproduce the EXPLAIN and on cold start a query of ~7 seconds, but my testdata isn't big enough to trigger the real slow down and possible deadlock. If you can make an anonymized dataset available, I will look into it.

Comment: I did opened the ticket at their support, they changed their logic and gave me the working PATCH. Works for us now! Sorry I forgot to come to this question then. I will upload that patch to the server and post it here when I get time so that someone with this issue can resolve it. Thanks Melvyn for your help!

Comment: Thanks. If it's been patched I'll check the merchant's account for it and ask around if it's not generally available :) Just out of curiousity, how many records in sales_flat_quote so I can get a ballpark on the breakpoint?

Comment: Ok thanks. I had around 190000 records.

Answer (score 1):

As said, this join can be very bad on large order item collections, cause it can't reference the catalog_category_entity table. Same goes for quote_item to CCE. So we have a join in the middle that can't use an indexed approach to it's outer parts. In worst case, MySQL tries to sort it over and over to get optimal alignment of CCE.

I'd to it like this:

1. Join the quotes with quote_item and put the is_active on the join condition and keep the GROUP BY.
2. Fetch all quote_item.product_id into an array
3. Fetch price info using IN($quote_item_product_ids)
4. Fetch times sold till now using order_items.product_id IN($quote_item_product_ids)

And/or create an index table linking sold quantities to product entities. A foreign key there can work, cause in the index table we can make the item_id columns nullable, what can't be done with a primary key.